# CSV table without encoding

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to import a csv table that contain special characters to R, but when I load it some characters seem to lose the encoding.

[image]

Here's the code I'm using.

```
mobilidade_urbana <- read.csv("Tabela Final - Cidades do Estudo de Caso - 02_09_2023.csv", sep = ";", dec = ".", encoding="UTF-8")
```

How do I correct this issue?

I tried to use the encoding on the function but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you try changing encoding for "Latin-1"?

Comment: It didn't work.
Usually using UTF-8 solves this problem...

Comment: My guess is the CSV has some non usual encoding, but I do not know a good way to detect which one. Could you try https://stringi.gagolewski.com/rapi/stri_enc_detect.html ? (and if you interested to learn more https://stringi.gagolewski.com/rapi/about_encoding.html#about-encoding)

Comment: Try `fileEncoding=` instead of `encoding=` .  Also look at `readr::guess_encoding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you haven't provided an example file, I think I can reproduce your issue on my machine, as someone who also uses files with portuguese diacritics.

The issue is **you're CSV file probably isn't in UTF-8 encoding to begin**, so including parameter encoding = "UTF-8" when running read.csv won't help.

To solve this, go into Excel and save your file with the following filetype/encoding:

[image: CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)]

A sample CSV file would be:

```
UF;MUNICIPIO
AL;Maceió
GO;Anápolis
```

Then try again using R:

```
df = read.csv("filename.csv", encoding="UTF-8", sep = ";")
```

If it still doesn't work, provide share the example file (with the encoding) and I can take a look in more detail :)

EDIT: adding sample CSV file for reproducibility.

Comment: Could you please mark as the answer for your question?  It would be my first actual answer here.

Comment: You know, RafaelBelokurows, you mention that the user doesn't have a reproducible question and then you don't provide a reproducible answer. It would be nice if you could add some raw text from the CSV file so that the rest of us can try to work through it. Thanks! (I also think there is a not-difficult way to adapt your method to not require Excel or Calc ...)